# return object without mutate in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is below function identical? I was using it in redux form, since my form is only one field I guess I need not to loop, but the second one does not behave the same I wonder why

```
//working
export default values => {
  let errors = {}
  ;['email'].forEach(field => {
    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = `Email cannot be empty.`
    }
  })
  return errors
}
```

versus

```
//is this the same as the above?
export default values => {
  if (!values.email) {
    return {
      errors: {
        email: `Email cannot be empty.`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is your first one `forEach`ing over a hard-coded array which has only a single value, and not even using the parameter in the callback? Seems a bit strange

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's how redux form work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two functions **are not** functionally equivalent.

Your first function **always** returns an object:

```
export default values => {
  let errors = {} // this errors object is always returned, regardless
                  // of the validity of fields
  ;['email'].forEach(field => {
    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = `Email cannot be empty.`
    }
  })
  return errors // Object always gets returned
}
```

Your second function however, **only returns an object** if `values.email` is falsey:

```
export default values => {
  if (!values.email) {
    // Result only returned if !values.email
    return {
      errors: {
        email: `Email cannot be empty.`
      }
    }
  }
  // If values.email is "truthy", then undefined is returned
}
```

In summary, the second function returns a defined result if if `values.email` is falsey and undefined if `values.email` is truthy, which differs from your first function, which returns a defined result in all cases.

You could consider the following change to your second function to make it behave in a similar way to the first:

```
export default values => {
  if (!values.email) {
    return {
      errors: {
        email: `Email cannot be empty.`
      }
    }
  }
  // If values.email is "truthy", then return empty error object
  return {}
}
```

Comment: @charlietfl what else are you seeing that I've missed?